# How to write ST_Project method in C# using NetTopologySuite

Tags: postgis, c#, nettopologysuite

I would like to write a method in C# (+NetTopologySuite) which works like ST_Project in PostGIS (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html).
So the argements are: input coordinates, distance, azimuth

Returns a point projected from a start point using a given distance and azimuth. The distance is given in the cordinate system unit.

How to do this?

```
Coordinate ST_Project (Coordinate inputCoordinate, double distance, double azimuth)
{
}
```

Comment: You will have to either implement [*Vincenty's Direct Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_problem) yourself, or wrap one of the various implementations that are surely available in the *C#* eco-system.

Comment: [First search result](https://gist.github.com/jhmt/f57c44139cf09a532c7efa60c6158913) for [*c# vincenty's formulae*](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=c%23+vincenty%27s+formulae&ia=web).